# Display return data from after lifting state up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm using lifting state up Component ContextualMenu return the object:

```
const action = (type) => {
     console.log(type);
     setData('description', type.description)
}
//...
<ContextualMenu action={action} />
<p>{data.description}</p>
```

This code is simplified but with its help I can show the problem. Action method return correctly object which looks like this:

```
{
   id: 1,
   description: 'Hello World'
//...
}
```

Into action method `console.log` return correctly object but correctly value it's didn't display in the paragraph `<p>{data.description}</p>`. It doesn't change. Could you help me?

Comment: Can you paste the setData function? it seems you don't update the state.

Comment: I'm using Breeze so setData it's useState. This is works correctly.

Comment: This simplified code is not complete and cannot reflect your components logic. Please paste the rest of the relevant components.